# Response failed with server

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-networking

I hava a express server to send data to and from the server for my mobile app.
this is what my express server sends back from my post request I send on my app to the server

```
then(() => { console.log("ok send"); res.status(200).send("ok")}).catch((err) => {console.log(err); res.status(400).send('error')})
```

The post request gets send and recieved by the server and I want te server to send an Ok response back to the app. It does this correct because I get an ok send in console. In the mobile app I use a AsyncHttpClient.

```
 AsyncHttpClient.post("/url/" + id,json,new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);

            System.out.println("succes");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statuscode,Header[] headers, String response, Throwable trowable){
            super.onFailure(statuscode,headers,response,trowable);
            System.out.println("fail");
            System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println("statuscode = " + statuscode);

        }




    });
```

When I recieve the ok back it automatically goes to the onFailure even if statuscode = 200.
And android gives a semi error message:

> W/JsonHttpRH: onFailure(int, Header[], String, Throwable) was not overriden, but callback was received
>       org.json.JSONException: Response cannot be parsed as JSON data

How would I be able to fix this problem and make it go to onsucces ?
thx

Comment: it clearly showing 'Response cannot be parsed as JSON data', Ccheck your response format, is it in json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change JsonHttpResponseHandler to TextHttpResponseHandler

```
client.post("/url/" + id,json,new TextHttpResponseHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response) {
        System.out.println("succes");

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statuscode,Header[] headers, String response, Throwable trowable){
        System.out.println("fail");
        System.out.println(response);
        System.out.println("statuscode = " + statuscode);

    }
});
```